# aws-amplify initialization failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I did install aws-amplifier cli and configured as given in official documentation.
But when I try to run `amplify init`, I got the following error.
[image]

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Do you have admin access right?

Comment: yes, I do have admin access

Comment: Have you got profile?check C:\Users\Asus\.aws\credentials

Comment: yes, I just add .aws folder into SPB_data folder and it worked...!